# Problems with Resharper? VS 2015 and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resharper, resharper-9.0

I got VS 2015 and MVC, i get this red stuff in several projects. What can be the cause. Views is the only problem, works fine in code behind.

[image: MVC View]

Answer (score 0):

add below in web.config(Inside View folder web.config as well outside web.config)

```
   <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />

  </namespaces>
```